# "Response 401: The key used is invalid, malformed, empty, or doesn't match the region" while working with Dispatch

Tags: nlp, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm getting this error because Dispatch does not like my either my QnAKnowledgebaseId or QnAEndpointKey located in my .env file. I know the Id and Key are correct because I've tripled checked it and made sure the Id and Key came from my qna.ai portal. Somehow when dispatchbot.js is loaded up, it does not like my Id or Key:

```
const qnaMaker = new QnAMaker({
            knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
            endpointKey: process.env.QnAEndpointKey,
            host: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
});
```

Anyone have any idea why I am still getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the wrong LuisAPIKey, not anything to do with the QnA Maker Ids and Keys. For anyone wondering, the LUISAPIKey for working with Dispatch is the Luis Authoring Resource value.